# ContextMenu issue in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, contextmenu, uibarbuttonitem

I put `UIBarButtonItem` inside `Toolbar` as you can see in `Storyboard`. I put `UIMenu` in `UIBarButtonItem.menu`. When I click a button in `UIMenu`, the icon of the button I clicked is transferred to `UIBarButtonItem`. Why is this happening?

**Question:**

**Why does the UIBarButtonItem's icon change when I press the button from ContextMenu?**

**Video:**

[image]

**Storyboard:**

[image]

**UIBarButtonItem Attributes:**

[image]

**ViewController:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var fooItem: UIBarButtonItem!

//MARK: Functions
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fooItem.menu = ContextMenuManager.shared.makeUIMenu()
}
```

**ContextMenuManager:**

```
protocol ContextMenuFunctionable {
    func didTappedEmptyFolder()
    func didTappedImportFile()
}

class ContextMenuManager {
    
    static var shared = ContextMenuManager()
    
    var delegate: ContextMenuFunctionable?
    var emptyFolder: UIAction?
    var importFile: UIAction?
    var importPhotoOrVideo: UIAction?
    
    private init() {
        
        emptyFolder = UIAction(
            title: "Empty Folder",
            image: .folderBadgePlus
                .applyingSymbolConfiguration(.symbolConfig),
            identifier: nil,
            state: .off,
            handler: { _ in self.delegate?.didTappedEmptyFolder() }
        )
        
        importFile = UIAction(
            title: "Import File",
            image: .squareAndArrowDown.applyingSymbolConfiguration(.symbolConfig),
            identifier: nil,
            state: .off,
            handler: { _ in self.delegate?.didTappedImportFile() }
        )
        
        importPhotoOrVideo = UIAction(
            title: "Import Photo & Video",
            image: .photo.applyingSymbolConfiguration(.symbolConfig),
            identifier: nil,
            state: .off,
            handler: { _ in self.delegate?.didTappedImportFile() }
        )
    }

    
    func makeUIMenu() -> UIMenu {
        guard let emptyFolder, let importFile, let importPhotoOrVideo else { return UIMenu() }
        return UIMenu(title: "Add",
                      image: .folder.applyingSymbolConfiguration(.symbolConfig),
                      options: [.displayInline, .singleSelection],
               children: [importPhotoOrVideo, importFile, emptyFolder])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the "Selection as Primary Action" checkbox and the button's icon should no longer change when you make a menu selection.

I replicated what you are seeing in code. I created a menu basically using your `ContextMenuManager` code but I created the `UIBarButtonItem` as follows:

```swift
let menu = UIMenu(title: "Add",
                  options: [.displayInline, .singleSelection],
                  children: [importPhotoOrVideo, importFile, emptyFolder])

let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "doc.on.clipboard.fill"), menu: menu)
button.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = false
```

When `changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction` is set to `true`, the button's icon reflects the chosen menu. When set to `false`, it retains its own icon.